# Categorizing and creating a sentence using number values

Tags: r

I have a matrix that looks like this:

```
canada <- c(10, 20, 90)
korea <- c(60, 30, 90)
iran <- c(20, 20, 40)
fruit <- rbind(canada, korea, iran)
colnames(fruit) <- c("apple", "banana", "orange")
```

I want it to look like this:

```
price("canada")
> Canada has affordable fruits, but buying an orange is expensive. They cost 90 cents each.
```

So, thanks to some folks at StackOverflow, I have this:

```
price <- function(val){
  val <- tolower(val) # assuming all row names are in lower case
  myrow <- fruit[val,]
  nation <- tools::toTitleCase(val)

  # Apple Prices
  apple <- sapply(seq_along(myrow), 
                      function(x, n, i) {paste0(x[i], ".")}, 
                      x=myrow[1], n=names(myrow))
  apple[length(apple)] <- paste0(apple[length(apple)])
  apple <- paste(apple[1])

  # Banana Prices
  banana <- sapply(seq_along(myrow), 
                   function(x, n, i) {paste0(x[i], ".")}, 
                   x=myrow[2], n=names(myrow))
  banana[length(banana)] <- paste0(banana[length(banana)])
  banana <- paste(banana[1])

  # Orange Prices
  orange <- sapply(seq_along(myrow), 
                   function(x, n, i) {paste0(x[i], ".")}, 
                   x=myrow[3], n=names(myrow))
  orange[length(orange)] <- paste0(orange[length(orange)])
  orange <- paste(orange[1])

  if(myrow[1] > 30 | myrow[2] > 30 | myrow[3] > 30)
    cat("This is my limit, and I need to push myself over the edge to learn more.")
}

price("canada")
```

The idea is that I can have as many selections of fruits and be able to extract a select number of fruits that are expensive and say "... but, ((fruit names here)) are expensive." It would also be nice if I can mention the price of the expensive fruits, but I would be satisfied with just mentioning the name of those expensive fruits.

Comment: A few considerations: would any fruit be considered expensive in Iran? And would any fruit be considered affordable in Korea?

Comment: I would strongly suggest you to use a different data storage solution. More specifically, a 3 column data.frame, where you have country, fruit.type, and fruit.price.

Comment: @csgroen: Yes, of course. But, I want to call by countries. So, if I typed price("canada"), then I would obtain values only from Canada. Similarly, if I typed price("iran"), then I would get something similar. 

I guess a fair price could be 30

Comment: @ Damiano: Thank you for the suggestion. Currently, the bulkier version of the script is written in a matrix, so that's why I am working with these kinds. I wish to broaden my knowledge as time progresses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This selects a fruit as expensive if it's at least 2/3 as expensive as the most expensive fruit. The phrasing is a bit different ("oranges" instead of "an orange") to allow for multiple fruits. You can change that 2/3 max(fruit.prices) line to whatever makes the most sense to you. It can also be a fixed value.

```
price <- function(val){
    val <- tolower(val) # assuming all row names are in lower case
    myrow <- fruit[val,]
    nation <- tools::toTitleCase(val)

    fruit.prices <- fruit[val,]
    high.value <- 2/3 * max(fruit.prices)

    expensive.fruits <- fruit.prices[fruit.prices >= high.value]
    efruit.names <- paste0(names(expensive.fruits), "s", 
                               collapse = " and ")
    efruit.prices <- paste0(expensive.fruits, collapse = " and ")
    paste(nation, "has has affordable fruits, but buying", efruit.names,
          "is expensive. They cost", efruit.prices, "cents each.")

}
```

Output:

```
> price("canada")
[1] "Canada has has affordable fruits, but buying oranges is expensive. They cost 90 cents each."
> price("korea")
[1] "Korea has has affordable fruits, but buying apples and oranges is expensive. They cost 60 and 90 cents each."
> price("iran")
[1] "Iran has has affordable fruits, but buying oranges is expensive. They cost 40 cents each."
>
```

Comment: This will do! Thank you very much for your efforts. I appreciate your time very much.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this simplified function, which simply grabs the most expensive item with `which.max`

```
price <- function(val){
             val <- tolower(val) # assuming all row names are in lower case
             myrow <- fruit[val,]
             nation <- tools::toTitleCase(val)

             paste0(nation, " has affordable fruits, but buying an ", names(myrow)[which.max(c(myrow))], " is expensive. They cost ", c(myrow)[which.max(c(myrow))]," cents each.")
         }

price("canada")
```

#### Output

```
"Canada has affordable fruits, but buying an orange is expensive. They cost 90 cents each."
```

---

#### Printing fruits above a threshold price

```
price <- function(val,threshold){
             val <- tolower(val) # assuming all row names are in lower case
             myrow <- fruit[val,]
             nation <- tools::toTitleCase(val)

             paste0(nation, " has affordable fruits, but buying an ", paste0(names(myrow)[c(myrow)>threshold], collapse=" and "), " is expensive. They cost ", paste0(c(myrow)[c(myrow)>threshold], collapse=" and ")," cents each.")
     }

 price("korea",30)
```

#### Output

```
[1] "Korea has affordable fruits, but buying an apple and orange is expensive. They cost 60 and 90 cents each."
```

Comment: Wow! This is amazing. Would it be possible to select a value in lieu of [which.max]? For example, if the value is greater than 30, then R would list the names of those fruits costing more than 30.

Comment: It's possible but you'd have to specify your output. Separate sentences? Comma separated values?

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. Hopefully, there will come a day when I can contribute back to the community so that others can also learn to write R proficiently.

Answer (score 1):

I would work on a data.frame such as the one I suggested in the comments.

```
nu.fruit <- do.call(rbind, lapply(1:ncol(fruit), (function(i){
  do.call(rbind, lapply(1:nrow(fruit), (function(j){
    data.frame(country=rownames(fruit)[j], 
      fruit=colnames(fruit)[i],
      price=fruit[j,i])  
  })))  
})))
```

My solutions would be based on a threshold you can set. Here are the functions.

```
is.pricey <- function(country, data){

  # check arguments
  if ((!is.data.frame(data)) |
      (sum(c("country", "fruit", "price") %in% colnames(data)) != 3) |
      (length(country) != 1))
    stop("Bad input!")

  # retrieve cheapest fruit
  country <- tolower(country)
  tmp <- data[data[,"country"]== country,]
  if (nrow(tmp) > 0){
    my.max <- max(tmp[,"price"])
    return(tmp[tmp[,"price"] == my.max, ])
  } else {
    return(NULL)
  }
}

what.is.pricey <- function(country, data, threshold) {

  # check args
  if ((!is.numeric(threshold)) |
      (length(threshold) != 1))
    stop("Bad input!")

  # retrieve expensive items
  exp.stuff <- is.pricey(country,data)

  # check you have data and if they meet your conditions
  if (!is.null(exp.stuff)) {
    exp.stuff <- exp.stuff[exp.stuff[,"price"] >= threshold,]
    if (nrow(exp.stuff) > 0) {
      return(paste("Living in",
                   country,
                   "is cheap, but buying a",
                   exp.stuff$fruit, 
                   "costs", 
                   exp.stuff$price[1], collapse = ", "))   
    }
  }
}
```

And here the call

```
what.is.pricey(country = "korea", data = nu.fruit, threshold = 40)
```